# Delete user not working

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I want to be able to delete a user, but when I try to it throws the following error. "Error: The requested address '/cakephp/users/delete/8?url=users%2Fdelete%2F8' was not found on this server."

The code for my delete function is

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
        debug($this->User->delete());
        if (!$this->request->is('get')) 
        {
             throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }
        if ($this->User->delete($id)) 
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usermanage'));
        }
  }
```

**[NEW]**
I got rid of the usermanagement code and the index code to make room for my user model code..

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');
class User extends AppModel {

    public $primary_key = 'userID';
    public $validate = array(
        'username' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A username is required'
            )
        ),

        'password' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'A password is required'
            )
        ),
        'name' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your name is required'
            )
        ),
        'surname' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Your surname is required'
            )
        ),
        'memberType' => array(
            'valid' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'responder', 'volunteer')),
                'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        ),
        'address1' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your first line of address'
            )
        ),
        'address2' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your second line of address'
            )
        ),
        'town' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Please enter your town'
            )
        ),
        'postCode' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your postcode'
            )
        ),
        'dob' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your date of birth'
            )
        ),
        'emailAddress' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your email address'
            )
        ),
        'phoneNumber' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your phone number'
            )
        ),
        'mobileNumber' => array(
            'required' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'please enter your mobile number'
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please add the relevant routes to your post. Are other actions like edit and view working?

Comment: The edit function also does not work, i have created a question for that one, but had only unsuccessful answers :( i have now added the index page (which leads the user to the user management page)

Comment: Is `/cakephp` you document root?

Comment: yes the /cakephp is the root of my document

Comment: Without routes and urls we cannot five the best answer. If your edit also does not work there is something else wrong. Might be in routes or htaccess config.

Comment: You got another issue though. You probably have an invalid setup regarding your htaccess. Therefore it redirects to or displays /?url= instead of /? Take a look at the correct 2.x setup for htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error can be corrected in two ways (pickup one):

1 - Change your action delete to:

```
if (!$this->request->is('post') && !$this->request->is('put')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
}
```

2 - Not use postLink, and change delete action:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', $user['User']['userID'])); ?>

public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;

        if(!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }

        if ($this->User->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('The user with id: ' . $id . ' has been deleted.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usermanage'));
        }
}
```

**[EDIT]**
*For your primaryKey problem:*
In User model:

```
public $primary_key = 'userID';
```

In Other models (belongsTo, hasMany, hasBelongsToMany):

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'   => 'userID'
    )
);
```

Sorry for my english, I'm brazilian.

Comment: hello Patrick, thanks for your answer, i think i've made some progress... but the only problem i have left now is the sql statement seems to think that my user ID is called 'id' and not 'userID', how can i fix that problem?

Comment: You need to set the correct primary key for that model. [See documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-primarykey)

Comment: @patrick and noslone, i have now added the primary key in to the user model but it still try's to look for "id" as the primary key..

Comment: solved it, it should be $primaryKey not $primary_key.. yay thanks Patrick and Noslone!!!